# Handle a very large input file without slurp

Tags: json, jq

I am working with JSON output from a tool (massdns) that is formatted as follows:

```
{"query_name":"1eaff.example.com.","query_type":"A","resp_name":"ns02.example.com.","resp_type":"A","data":"<ip>"}
{"query_name":"1cf0e.example.com.","query_type":"A","resp_name":"ns01.example.com.","resp_type":"A","data":"<ip>"}
{"query_name":"1cf0e.example.com.","query_type":"A","resp_name":"ns02.example.com.","resp_type":"A","data":"<ip>"}
{"query_name":"1fwsjz2f4ok1ot2hh2illyd1-wpengine.example.com.","query_type":"A","resp_name":"ns01.example.com.","resp_type":"A","data":"<ip>"}
{"query_name":"1fwsjz2f4ok1ot2hh2illyd1-wpengine.example.com.","query_type":"A","resp_name":"ns02.example.com.","resp_type":"A","data":"<ip>"}
{"query_name":"1a811.example.com.","query_type":"A","resp_name":"ns01.example.com.","resp_type":"A","data":"<ip>"}
```

I am able to use `jq` with slurp (`-s`) to beautifully output the results in the format I need:

```
jq -s '{ a: "xxx", "b": 123, domains: map(select(.resp_type=="A") | .resp_name[:-1] ) | unique }'
```

This yields a JSON string like:

```
{
  "a": "xxx",
  "b": 123,
  "domains": [
    "ns01.example.com",
    "ns02.example.com"
  ]
}
```

(See [JQPlay example here](https://jqplay.org/s/MdvCSywoMI).)

My problem occurs when my input scales to hundreds of thousands of lines (GBs of data), in which case slurp becomes too memory-consuming, and `jq` exits with an error.

I have discovered the `--stream` option, which allows handling large inputs, but am struggling to find a way to obtain the same output. Is there a way to use `--stream` (and not `--slurp`) to get the wanted output for a very large input file with `jq`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--stream` would overcomplicate this task, use `--null-input/-n` option in conjunction with `reduce` instead.

```
{a: "xxx", b: 123}
| .domains = (reduce (inputs|select(.query_type == "A").resp_name) as $d
  ({}; . + {($d): null}) | keys_unsorted | map(.[:-1]))
```

Keeping domains in an object as keys instead of an array makes this script even more efficient in terms of memory consumption and cpu time; in jq, *Objects are added by merging, that is, inserting all the key-value pairs from both objects into a single combined object. If both objects contain a value for the same key, the object on the right of the `+` wins.* Thus no need to `unique`.

Trimming the last char off (`.[:-1]`) all `resp_name`s slows down the process as well, performing `map(.[:-1])` on resulting array instead is more efficient.

See it on [jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/tmbvmX-axL).

Comment: This seems to work well. When testing in jqplay, this also works without the `--null-input` flag on. Is that expected? Also love your suggested performance improvements. Thanks!

Comment: @Honoki without `-n` first object of input is ignored.